# C++ - Strange behaviour with template parameters that are different but have same name

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, namespaces

I ran into some strange thing with template parameters.

Basically, I have two cpp files with different structs defined in them but with the same name. (both in anonymous namespace.) When I pass the structs to a templated function, the same template instance of that function is being called. That one sees both structures as same.

I don't understand if this is a compiler bug or am I just being a newbie.

In my real-world code this lead to a nasty bug so I wrote a simple test. (I omitted the header guards here.)

SomeFunc.hpp:

```
template<typename T> int someFunc(const T& obj) {
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

Test1.hpp:

```
int testFunc1();
```

Test1.cpp:

```
#include "Test1.hpp"

#include "SomeFunc.hpp"

struct CTestStruct{int a; int b; float c;};

int testFunc1() {
    CTestStruct test_sturct; 
    return someFunc( test_sturct);
}
```

Test2.hpp:

```
int testFunc2();
```

Test2.cpp:

```
#include "Test2.hpp"

#include "SomeFunc.hpp"

struct CTestStruct{char a; float b;};

int testFunc2() {
    CTestStruct test_sturct; 
    return someFunc( test_sturct);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Test1.hpp"
#include "Test2.hpp"

int main(){

    std::cout << testFunc1() << "\n";
    std::cout << testFunc2() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
12
```

The problem is that testFunc1 and testFunc2 see two different structures, but someFunc treats them as the same. When I modify testFunc1 to `{return 0;}` (so no template instance is generated for that sturct) the output is:

```
0
8
```

Compiler is GCC 7.3.0.

Comment: You wrote about anonymous namespaces in your question but you have none in your snippets. These could clearly alter the behaviour of the code.

Comment: In `main.cpp` you will encounter two definitions for the same type. It should generates a compilation error.

Comment: You are violating ODR.  You can't have the same class defined two different ways.

Comment: That code has both definitions in the global namespace, which is undefined.

Comment: As @NathanOliver mentioned already this is a clear violation of  One Definition Rule (ODR). In this case, only one of the two definitions of `CTestStruct` will be selected by the linker during symbol resolving process and other definition will be left out. Which of the two definitions will be selected is uncertain. Hence this is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @army007 I see. Is it normal to not get any warning whatsoever?

Comment: @AdyAdy, yes it is normal not to get any warning about ODR.

Comment: @army007 Thank you! Is there any convention how to avoid this? Is it simply a bad practice to define anything in the cpp files like that?

Comment: @AdyAdy Put the definitions inside anonymous namespaces. (You claim that you already are, but your code says that you’re not.) It’s a good habit to do that with everything that should be confined to one source file.

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought no namespace means the anonymous namespace, my bad.

Comment: Not sure if there is any convention. But, you can put things in the separate namespace. Defining things in a source file (.cpp) is not a bad idea. Sometimes things that are not needed outside of the file are defined in the source and given internal linkage. Internal linkage can be provided by keeping definitions inside an anonymous namespace (a namespace without a name), don't confuse it with global namespace (no namespace).

Comment: @AdyAdy It's not easy to guess that "anonymous namespace" has a special meaning and doesn't include "the namespace that has no name, but is global".